# c# Adding a Remove(int index) method to the .NET Queue class

Tags: c#, queue

I would like to use the generic queue class as described in the .NET framework (3.5)
but I will need a Remove(int index) method to remove items from the queue. Can I achieve this functionality with an extension method? Anyone care to point me in the right direction?

Comment: To those claiming this would defeat the purpose of a queue, I have a use case for this feature. Suppose your queue has items with an expiration time and the item consumer may temporarily be busy or items need to be sent over a network and the host is temporarily unreachable or the network is down. You would want to purge expired items from the queue before returning "queue full" in response to a queue attempt.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you want is a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) where you always call [`RemoveAt(0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c93ab5c9.aspx) when you want to get the item from the `Queue`.  Everything else is the same, really (calling `Add` would add an item to the end of the `Queue`).

Comment: This has the disadvantage of making `Dequeue`s O(n) instead of O(1)

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Of course, if you're using a Queue the assumption is that you don't need random access in the first place.  Wrong data structure it would seem.

Comment: If removeat is only happening occassionaly, then it makes sense to keep the Queue structure, but rebuild it minus the one item. I've added my answer for detail.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I realize it seems like that performance degradation would occur, but after finding out [`Queue`s, `Stack`s, and `Lists`s are all backed by an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000410/why-are-stackt-and-queuet-implemented-with-an-array), I've stopped taking implementations for granted. Do you have benchmarks suggesting or confirming your claim? As [this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380715/1028230), Queues "_will expose your **intent** more explicitly_", but the big O loss isn't as obvious [to me] as it might seem. (I would hope Queue is faster; but is it?)

Comment: @ruffin `List<T>` moves all later elements when removing an element, which means moving all elements when removing the first. `Queue<T>` uses the backing array as a ring-buffer which enables fast dequeuing.

Answer (score 18):

Here's how you remove a **specific** item from the queue with one line of Linq (it's recreating the queue, BUT for the lack of a better method...)

```
//replace "<string>" with your actual underlying type
myqueue = new Queue<string>(myqueue.Where(s => s != itemToBeRemoved));
```

I know it's not removing **by index**, but still, someone might find this useful (this question ranks in Google for "remove specific item from a c# queue" so I decided to add this answer, sorry)

Comment: This also helps to filter multiple items if you have a queue that contains a number of items you wish to remove, a lá `myqueue= new Queue<object>(myqueue.Where(x => x.Param != "foo"))`

Answer (score 15):

Combining both casperOne's and David Anderson's suggestions to the next level.  The following class inherits from List and hides the methods that would be detrimental to the FIFO concept while adding the three Queue methods (Equeue, Dequeu, Peek).

```
public class ListQueue<T> : List<T>
{
    new public void Add(T item) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Insert(int index, T item) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void InsertRange(int index, IEnumerable<T> collection) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Reverse() { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Reverse(int index, int count) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Sort() { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Sort(Comparison<T> comparison) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Sort(IComparer<T> comparer) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    new public void Sort(int index, int count, IComparer<T> comparer) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        var t = base[0]; 
        base.RemoveAt(0);
        return t;
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        return base[0];
    }
}
```

**Test code:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ListQueue<string> queue = new ListQueue<string>();

        Console.WriteLine("Item count in ListQueue: {0}", queue.Count);
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var text = String.Format("Test{0}", i);
            queue.Enqueue(text);
            Console.WriteLine("Just enqueued: {0}", text);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Item count in ListQueue: {0}", queue.Count);
        Console.WriteLine();

        var peekText = queue.Peek();
        Console.WriteLine("Just peeked at: {0}", peekText);
        Console.WriteLine();

        var textToRemove = "Test5";
        queue.Remove(textToRemove);
        Console.WriteLine("Just removed: {0}", textToRemove);
        Console.WriteLine();

        var queueCount = queue.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < queueCount; i++)
        {
            var text = queue.Dequeue();
            Console.WriteLine("Just dequeued: {0}", text);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Item count in ListQueue: {0}", queue.Count);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Now try to ADD an item...should cause an exception.");
        queue.Add("shouldFail");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

It's a pretty late answer but I write it for future readers

`List<T>` is exactly what you need but it has a big disadvantage when compared to `Queue<T>`: it's implemented with an array then `Dequeue()` is pretty expansive (in terms of time) because all items must be shifted one step back with `Array.Copy`. Even `Queue<T>` uses an array but together with two indices (for head and tail).

In your case you also need `Remove`/`RemoveAt` and its performance won't be good (for the same reason: if you're not removing from list tail then another array must be allocated and items copied).

A better data structure to have quick `Dequeue`/`Remove` time is a linked list (you'll sacrifice - a little bit - performance for `Enqueue` but assuming your queue has an equal number of `Enqueue`/`Dequeue` operations you'll have a great gain in performance, especially when its size will grow).

Let's see a simple skeleton for its implementation (I'll skip implementation for `IEnumerable<T>`, `IList<T>` and other helper methods).

```
class LinkedQueue<T>
{
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _items.Count; }
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        _items.AddLast(item);
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (_items.First == null)
           throw new InvalidOperationException("...");

        var item = _items.First.Value;
        _items.RemoveFirst();

        return item;
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        _items.Remove(item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        Remove(_items.Skip(index).First());
    }

    private LinkedList<T> _items = new LinkedList<T>();
}
```

For a quick comparison:

```
           Queue            List              LinkedList
Enqueue    O(1)/O(n)*       O(1)/O(n)*        O(1)
Dequeue    O(1)             O(n)              O(1)
Remove     n/a              O(n)              O(n)
```

<sup>*</sup> O(1) is *typical* case but *sometimes* it'll be O(n) (when internal array need to be resized).

Of course you'll pay something for what you gain: memory usage is bigger (especially for small `T` overhead will be great). Right implementation (`List<T>` vs `LinkedList<T>`) must be chosen carefully according to your usage scenario, you may also convert that code to use a single linked list to reduce 50% of memory overhead.

Answer (score 8):

Although there isn't a built-in way, you shouldn't use a List structure or other structure, IFF RemoveAt isn't a frequent operation.

If you are normally enqueuing and dequeuing but only occasionally removing, then you should be able to afford a queue rebuild when removing.

```
public static void Remove<T>(this Queue<T> queue, T itemToRemove) where T : class
{
    var list = queue.ToList(); //Needs to be copy, so we can clear the queue
    queue.Clear();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (item == itemToRemove)
            continue;

        queue.Enqueue(item);
    }
}

public static void RemoveAt<T>(this Queue<T> queue, int itemIndex) 
{
    var list = queue.ToList(); //Needs to be copy, so we can clear the queue
    queue.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == itemIndex)
            continue;

        queue.Enqueue(list[i]);
    }
}
```

The following approach might be more efficient, using less memory, and thus less GC:

```
public static void RemoveAt<T>(this Queue<T> queue, int itemIndex)
{
    var cycleAmount = queue.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < cycleAmount; i++)
    {
        T item = queue.Dequeue();
        if (i == itemIndex)
            continue;

        queue.Enqueue(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer this when Enqueue/Dequeue operations are much higher compare to remove method. Thanks Todd

Comment: This is awesome when occasionally removing elements in a queue. May need other implementations or choose other data structures when frequently removing elements. Anyway, this answer is awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Someone will probably develop a better solution, but from what I see you will need to return a new Queue object in your Remove method. You'll want to check if the index is out of bounds and I may have got the ordering of the items being added wrong, but here's a quick and dirty example that could be made into an extension quite easily.

```
public class MyQueue<T> : Queue<T> {
    public MyQueue() 
        : base() {
        // Default constructor
    }

    public MyQueue(Int32 capacity)
        : base(capacity) {
        // Default constructor
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the item at the specified index and returns a new Queue
    /// </summary>
    public MyQueue<T> RemoveAt(Int32 index) {
        MyQueue<T> retVal = new MyQueue<T>(Count - 1);

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < this.Count - 1; i++) {
            if (i != index) {
                retVal.Enqueue(this.ElementAt(i));
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David,

That looks interesting, but surely there is quite some overhead for creating a new queue like this everytime?

Perhaps I am better off solving the inverse problem: just use a list and making my own Queue,Peek and Dequeue methods?

Comment: I wrote a blog on this a few minutes ago that should answer any questions about the code I posted.

http://renevo.com/blogs/developer/archive/2009/02/10/a-bad-approach-to-adding-removeat-to-a-queue-t.aspx

Comment: Your for loop does not seem correct. I don't see a reason for not iterating through all the queue items. The correct is for (Int32 i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)

Comment: You *mustn't* call ElementAt inside of RemoveAt. You've changed an O(n) operation of copying the queue - already bad - into an O(n^2) operation, as ElementAt iterates through all the elements up to the passed index to find it's element - on *every single iteration of the loop*. Far better to use foreach and skip the offending element via a loop counter in O(n) time.

Comment: My implementation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20566992/921321) is O(n) and modifies the existing `Queue<T>` rather than returning a new one.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe we should be using `List<T>` to emulate a queue, for a queue, the enqueue and dequeue operations should be very highly performant, which they would not be when using a `List<T>`. For the `RemoveAt` method however, it is acceptable to be non-performant, as it is not the primary purpose of a `Queue<T>`.

My approach at implementing `RemoveAt` is O(n) but the queue still maintains a largely O(1) enqueue (sometimes the internal array needs reallocating which makes the operations O(n)) and always O(1) dequeue.

Here is my implementation of a `RemoveAt(int)` extension method for a `Queue<T>`:

```
public static void RemoveAt<T>(this Queue<T> queue, int index)
{
    Contract.Requires(queue != null);
    Contract.Requires(index >= 0);
    Contract.Requires(index < queue.Count);

    var i = 0;

    // Move all the items before the one to remove to the back
    for (; i < index; ++i)
    {
        queue.MoveHeadToTail();
    }

    // Remove the item at the index
    queue.Dequeue();

    // Move all subsequent items to the tail end of the queue.
    var queueCount = queue.Count;
    for (; i < queueCount; ++i)
    {
        queue.MoveHeadToTail();
    }
}
```

Where `MoveHeadToTail` is defined as follows:

```
private static void MoveHeadToTail<T>(this Queue<T> queue)
{
    Contract.Requires(queue != null);

    var dequed = queue.Dequeue();
    queue.Enqueue(dequed);
}
```

This implementation also modifies the actual `Queue<T>` rather than returning a new `Queue<T>` (which I think is more in-keeping with other `RemoveAt` implementations).

Comment: Hello, I really like your solution. However, if index to remove is 0, you'll have a bug. After the first dequeue you could test if index was 0 and then just return.

Comment: @Roberto Are you sure about that? if index is 0 then it doesn't do any of the MoveHeadToTail calls and just a single dequeue

Comment: Hello @Lukazoid. Thanks for replying. After your reply, I have written a unit test in order to be 100% sure.
Indeed there is no bug when removing the first element from the queue. 
Nevertheless, the operation will be O(n) unless you return before the second loop.
Thank you again for your answer, it was helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this defeats the whole purpose of Queue and the class you'll eventually come up with the will violate the FIFO semantics altogether.

Comment: Yep, and that goes for any specialized collection. (Stack, Queue, other). If it doesn't do what you want, its not the right collection to use.

Answer (score 2):

If the Queue is being used to preserve the order of the items in the collection, and if you will not have duplicate items, then a [SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) might be what you are looking for. The `SortedSet` acts much like a `List<T>`, but stays ordered. Great for things like drop down selections.

Comment: SortedSet is only available in .NET 4 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

[David Anderson's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531191/c-adding-a-removeint-index-method-to-the-net-queue-class/531201#531201) is probably the best but has some overhead.
Are you using custom objects in the queue? if so, add a boolean like cancel

Check with your workers that process the queue if that boolean is set and then skip it.

Comment: Don't ask questions in a answer. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree. The answer you mention creates a new instance of the queue. This would suffice to force de code to get the new instance after each RemoveAt method call.

Answer (score 0):

Note that with a list you can make the "removal" process more efficient if you don't actually remove the item but merely "mark" it as "removed". Yes, you have to add a bit of code to deal with how you've done it, but the payoff is the efficiency.

Just as one example - Say you have a `List<string>`. Then you can, for example, just set that particular item to null and be done with it.

Answer (score -3):

The queue class is so difficult to understand. Use a generic list instead.

Comment: On contrary, it is very easy to understand it. Only thing you have to do is invest a few extra minutes to learn about it and open a whole new world of simplicity, in contrast to generic list.