# Is sorting a list the best solution?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I'm doing a program for school, and am trying to decide how I should go about it.

It's a restaurant simulation. I generate a random list of tables and of waiting parties. I randomly have some parties with reservations some without on the waiting list. I want the parties with reservations to have first priority.

Is sorting the list so that all parties with reservations are on one end and ones without another a good way to go about this?

Then I can just evaluate the list in order see if the party will fit at the table, then seat them or move on to the next party. Or is there a smarter way to go about this? Any input appreciated!

Comment: Loop once and take care of reservations, then once more to take care of everyone else. What you need is more like filtering the collection of parties and less like sorting -- although of course sorting can partition the list and make filtering very easy, that's just a means to an end and probably not really worth it.

Comment: For the restaurant to be efficient, you'd want it so that it is never possible to have more reservations than there are seats. A reservation should mean that the person always gets a seat at a table, irrespective of their order. If No of reservations = No of seats then you don't care about the other list. However, if No of reservations < No of Seats, then you want to allocate seats to people in the waiting list. Best way to do that is in order of their arrival - i.e. first come first served. Therefore, I would only sort the list of people without reservations, and in the order they arrived.

Comment: Sorting them by reservation seems reasonable. I'd run with your idea as it stands and see where it takes you.

Comment: @dash You'd probably need more smarts than just the order of arrival. If there's a party of 4 at the front of the queue but you have a free table for two you'd need to peek further.

Comment: @JRoughan agree, but it should never be necessary to sort the list of people with reservations; it's only necessary to divide the people into two groups, With and Without reservations. The only sorting you then need to do is on the group without reservations, and, in that instance, you want to `take` the first party of people that match the number of empty seats (tables) you have, sorted by order of arrival. In this instance, a List might not be the best construct; a Queue consisting of Party objects might be better, as you can immediately remove Party where Reservation = true.

Comment: I successfully sorted the list and that's what I was thinking once it's sorted so I know my Reservation people are first. Then I can check the first group see if they fit the table that just opened on my timer tick if not keep moving down the list until a group fits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var groupedParties = parties.GroupBy(p => p.HasReservation);
```

That's the cleanest way I see so far. You get a list of two groups, containg one with the parties without and one with the parties with reservations. You can now handle seating of the different kinds of waiting parties seperately.

### EDIT

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GenerateRandomDataSomehow();
    var groupedParties = _parties.GroupBy(p => p.HasReservation)
    SeatParty(groupedParties.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key == true));
    SeatParty(groupedParties.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key == false));
}

private static void SeatParty(IEnumerable<Party> partyGroup)
{
    if (partyGroup == null) return;

    foreach (var party in partyGroup.OrderBy(p => p.ArrivalTime))
    {
        var properTable = _tables.FirstOrDefault(t => t.SeatsCount == party.PersonsCount &&
                                                      t.Party == null);
        if (properTable == null) continue;
        properTable.Party = party;
    }
}
```

Here a very simple implementation with more LINQ. The selection criteria needs to be extended properly. In this table gets evaluated as "proper" if no other party is seated on this table, yet and if the persons count is exact the seats count of the corresponding table. The group is skipped if no proper table can be found.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to model your restaurant using a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) or a queue like construct, rather than a List and adopt a different approach. This way, you'll be storing people in the order they arrive so no sorting is necessary.

Group people into a Party object. As Parties arrive, you can add them to the queue. You can then look through the queue, and, if a Party has a reservation, you remove them from the queue and send them to their table. If the party doesn't have a reservation, then you check to see if a table is available for a party of that size, and, if it is, remove the party from the queue.

Otherwise, you can wait until a Table becomes available; when that event happens, you can then walk the queue again, looking for a party that fits the table size. You can also check to see if the Queue contains a Party with a Reservation at this point, which means they take priority - use `Queue.First(x => x.HasReservation && x.Size <= Table.Places)` to take the first set of people from the queue that have a reservation and can fit at the table**. Otherwise, `Queue.First(x => x.Size <= Table.Places)` will get you the first set of people on the queue that fit at the table.

The advantage of using a queue is that no sorting is necessary, you process parties of people in the order that they arrive, giving precedence to people with reservations.

You check the queue at two points:

1. When people arrive (do they have a reservation, is a table available)
2. When a table becomes available - first look for people in the queue with a reservation and being able to fit at the table; if no matches, then take the first set of people from the queue that match the table size (or can fit at the table)

That's a good place to start.

UPDATE

As you've discovered, you can't remove an item from the middle of a queue. This is because a Queue is First in First Out (FIFO) [as opposed to a Stack which is Last In First Out - LIFO]. In order to avoid sorting, you can use a List with Queue like semantics - there is a good example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594375/is-there-a-better-way-to-implement-a-remove-method-for-a-queue).

** There is another interesting queueing problem here - that of efficiency. If a table with 4 places becomes available, what do you do? Give it to the first party that arrived that fits at the table, or give it to the largest party in the queue that fits at the table. Obviously, the first option is best for customer service as you are sitting people who have been waiting longest, but the second option maximises your profits as you are more fully utilizing tables :-)

Comment: Interesting i'm not familiar with Queue right now i'm playing with the sorting of the list and seeing how I can get that to work. The way you explain it though it seems like a better fit for the situation i'll have to experiment with a Queue too thanks.

Comment: @dsquaredtech A Queue is analogous to a Queue of people in real life; exactly what tends to happen when multiple people arrive at a restaurant :-) Good luck with your assignment, and, most importantly, have fun :-D

Comment: I had great success with sorting the list and with using a Queue. I think the queue was the smartest way to do it i'm changing the answer to this. Thanks dash!

Comment: In the end I wasn't successful with Queue because I could pull the correct value from the queue using FirstOrDefault but I couldn't Dequeue what I needed to theres no method to dequeue a specific thing as far as I could find.

Comment: @dsquaredtech I was hoping you'd ask that question! A queue is FIFO (First In First Out compare with `Stack` which is LIFO - Last In First Out) and now you've seen the issue with Removing items that aren't at the top of the queue (it's not designed for this). You can either maintain a few queues (Reserved Queue, Open Queue, with further queues for each party size) or you can use a List but enforce queue like semantics - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594375/is-there-a-better-way-to-implement-a-remove-method-for-a-queue for example. Either way, no, you don't need to sort the list :-)

Comment: Yeah after a bit more research I ended up going back to the lists and got everything to work successfully. Thanks for informing me about a Queue though I learned a lot from experimenting with it, and i'm sure in the future I will find a use for a Queue.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort your list:

Using `Enumerable.OrderByDescending`, `ThenByDescending`

```
var ordered = parties.OrderByDescending(p => p.HasReservation)
                     .ThenByDescending(p => p.PersonCount);
// if you want a new list use ordered.ToList()
foreach(var party in ordered)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you want to sort the original list you can use [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) with a custom delegate:

```
parties.Sort((p1, p2) =>
{
    if (p1.HasReservation != p2.HasReservation)
        return p1.HasReservation ? 1 : -1;
    else
        return p1.PersonCount.CompareTo(p2.PersonCount);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I think this will work perfectly for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.Linq` would probably be your best option for sorting your list in this situation.

something like:

```
var sorted = tables.OrderByDescending(o => o.IsReserved);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use two queues (assuming that your parties are represented by a type called `Party`. Change the type appropriately):

```
Queue<Party> withReservation = new Queue<Party>();
Queue<Party> withoutReservation = new Queue<Party>();
```

You can add a party to a queue like this:

```
if (party has reservation) { // (condition in pseudo code)
    withReservation.Enqueue(party);
} else {
    withoutReservation.Enqueue(party);
}
```

You would seat a party like this:

```
if (withReservation.Count > 0) {
    Seat(withReservation.Dequeue());
} else if (withoutReservation.Count > 0) {
    Seat(withoutReservation.Dequeue());
}
```