# Why does the underlying implementation of the queue in .NET use an array?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, queue

I'm currently reading C# In a Nutshell, and the book mentions that the underlying implementation of the Queue data structure uses an array that is resized as needed. There will of course be a cost to this resizing, so I'm wondering what the rationale behind using this over say a double linked list is? Given that we only care about the first and last element and that a double linked list resizes more efficiently than an array, why use the array? An array would take up less memory, but is that the only rationale?

EDIT:
Sorry, just realized this is almost an exact duplicate of this:
[Why are Stack<T> and Queue<T> implemented with an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000410/why-are-stackt-and-queuet-implemented-with-an-array?rq=1)
(Their question even came from the same book). Thanks for all your answers anyways!

Comment: You can try to correctly implement both and see which implementation is easier to prove working correctly as an approach to answer this question yourself...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Or just compare the performance...

Comment: @Servy - good option. Note that comparing performance may not be easy - reasonable implementations would have the same O(1) time for operations, and one would need to know a lot of GC to properly measure that portion of perf cost...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Big-O values and actual runtime performance (at a higher degree of precision) are radically different.  Just because a Linked List is O(1) doesn't mean it's just as fast.  If it's a constant value that just happens to be 10x more expensive, it's constant, but it's still more expensive.  A linked list has a lot of overhead involved in the allocation of node objects, resulting in more work for the GC, and also results in a likely loss or reduction in memory locality, thus resulting in more cache misses, which *greatly* harms performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an array as a circular buffer, as they did, is better for queues that can be assumed to have a maximum size. The growth of the array is the portion that makes it more expensive, so using an array is only preferable to doubly linked lists if you assume that the queue size won't continually expand, or that a valid maximum was supplied when the queue was created. A good explanation of circular buffers (that even mentions queues specifically) is present on [the all-knowing Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer):

> Circular buffering makes a good implementation strategy for a queue that has fixed maximum size. Should a maximum size be adopted for a queue, then a circular buffer is a completely ideal implementation; all queue operations are constant time. However, expanding a circular buffer requires shifting memory, which is comparatively costly. For arbitrarily expanding queues, a Linked list approach may be preferred instead.

In short, because most use cases won't involve arbitrarily expanding queues, and because, for those concerned about performance, a maximum can be supplied from the start, a backing array used as a circular buffer was used.

Answer (score 6):

For the same reasons a number of other data structures, like stacks, hash tables, adjacency lists, etc. are implemented using arrays instead of linked lists:

- With the de-facto standard resizing strategy, exponential growth, you only need two dozen resizing operations even if you start with an empty array and insert a few million items. And the first few resizing operations will only copy a couple of bytes.
- Queues in particular rarely grow without bound, so you can mostly avoid resizing.
- It's not just a bit more compact, a doubly-linked list of reference types of common value types (`int`) is a whole three times larger than the equivalent array, without even taking per-object allocation overhead into account. If we are honest and takes those into account, we must add a per-node header of one or two words, so it's more like 4x or 5x larger. This dwarfs any over-allocation the array may have.
- Due to being continuous, the array makes approximately infinitely much better use of the various caches. This affects practically any operation you can do on a queue except asking for its size, including resizing.
- All those list nodes would have to be allocated and garbage collected. While the generational GC should make allocation pretty cheap and should easily pick up nodes that only spend little time in the queue, it's still a lot of unnecessary work, and if the queue is large or rarely used, many nodes to survive a minor GC before being popped off the end of the queue, so there's that.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, double linked list is conceptually beautiful. But theoretically it requires each node be allocated with an isolated memory block, which is quite expensive. I believe any serious implementation of double linked list should actually use a pre-allocated memory block which expands/shrinks by portion as needed. That's why array is actually the ideal backend for implementing a queue.

Comment: It's not only the constant allocations that are expensive, but the fact that you lose memory locality since the objects within the structure are not located next to each other.  This makes iterating an array (or an array backed `Stack` *much, much* faster than a `LinkedList` that didn't happen to populate all of its objects at the same time.  Both have the same big-O factor, but adding lots of cache misses is a *big* deal.

Comment: Somewhat agreed. But for queue, you don't need iteration - you only want to push and pop :-)

Comment: In C# `Queue<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, and as such can actually be iterated.  It's also rather common to do a lot of adds or removes at the same time, which still benefits from the memory locality.