# Loop queue in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, queue

```
     public List<Transfer> Queue
     {
         get { return _queue; }
         set { _queue = value; }
     }
    TransferFromQueue()
    {
         // Do stuff
         // Remove transfered item from Queue
    }
```

My Queue is a variable to which items will be added and removed all the time.

I'm looking for a way to execute TransferFromQueue() whenever there are items in the list.
Though it should never be running more than one istance of TransferFromQueue().

How can I loop this queue one by one when there are items in the Queue?

Comment: Why don't you use a [`Queue<Transfer>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) instead?

Comment: Not sure, does it have any benefits over List<>?

Comment: Yes, edited my answer to provide a link to a question targeting this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you use a [`Queue<Transfer>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) instead? It seems to be exactly what you want.

```
private Queue<Transfer> _queue = new Queue<Transfer>();
public Queue<Transfer> Queue
{
    get { return _queue; }
    set { _queue = value; }
}

void TransferFromQueue()
{
    while(Queue.Count > 0)
    {
        Transfer current = Queue.Dequeue(); // removed
        // use Queue.Peek() if you want to look at it witout removing it
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Related:

[Queue<T> vs List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380692/queue-vs-list-in-c-sharp)