# In C#, Rotate a List to The Right by the specified numbers of places without using LINQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am trying to rotate a List of items to the right by the specified numbers of places without using LINQ and doing it the manual way, how am I able to do this?

I think I am not understanding how to approach/solve this problem in particular. Here's what I have tried so far.

A clear example of this problem could be something like this:
Initial Array(or List): 20,30,40,50,60,70
Rotate to the right by 3 places: 50,60,70,20,30,40

```
      public void Test(List<int> items, int places)
    {
        items.RemoveAt(places);
        items.Add(places);

    }
```

Comment: It will be more clear if you include an example, of list before this operation and list after this operation

Comment: You need circular queue data structure. Add items in circular queue and just keep moving the start position as required.

Comment: A clear example of this problem could be something like this: Initial Array(or List): 20,30,40,50,60,70 Rotate to the right by 3 places: 50,60,70,20,30,40

Comment: why is linq not allowed?

Comment: @Zerox the example you gave is a very special vase as it gives the same result for shifting 3 to the right and 3 to the left. I think it would have been better if you gave an example shifting 2 or 4 to the right.

Answer (score 5):

Results from the below:

```
20,30,40,50,60,70 
60,70,20,30,40,50  (Rotate 2) 
50,60,70,20,30,40  (Rotate 3)
```

If you meant to shift each element n indexes to the left, just replace the line `list[i] = copy[index];` with `list[index] = copy[i];`

Then you get these results:

```
20,30,40,50,60,70 
40,50,60,70,20,30  (Rotate 2) 
50,60,70,20,30,40  (Rotate 3)
```

This is a simple working generic method:

```
static void RotateList<T>(IList<T> list, int places)
{
    // circular.. Do Nothing
    if (places % list.Count == 0)
        return;

    T[] copy = new T[list.Count];
    list.CopyTo(copy, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        // % used to handle circular indexes and places > count case
        int index = (i + places) % list.Count;

        list[i] = copy[index];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 };
RotateList(list, 3);
```

Or since I'm a big fan of extension Methods, you can create one:

**(By using IList, this method works for arrays also)**

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void RotateList<T>(this IList<T> list, int places)
    {
        // circular.. Do Nothing
        if (places % list.Count == 0)
            return;

        T[] copy = new T[list.Count];
        list.CopyTo(copy, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            int index = (i + places) % list.Count;

            list[i] = copy[index];
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 };
list.RotateList(12); // circular - no changes

int[] arr = new int[] { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 };

arr.RotateList(3);
```

Comment: Is `i - 3;` assuming that `places` = 3?

Comment: should mod `places` by list length initially, else a `places` many times larger than list length will malfunction

Answer (score 4):

assuming you have a list `1-2-3-4-5`, and you want to shift it 2 right to : `3-4-5-1-2`.

```
for n = 1 to 2 
   remove the head, put it at the tail
```

simple loop with no linq.

Even though this sounds more like homework to me to be honest ..

Comment: as an afterthought, you can use an array, create a new one with same size, and simply copy with an offset ...

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] numbers = {20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};
int rotateBy = 3;
int[] rotated = new int[numbers.Length];

Array.Copy(numbers, rotateBy, rotated, 0, numbers.Length-rotateBy);
Array.Copy(numbers, 0, rotated, numbers.Length - rotateBy, rotateBy);
```

Answer (score 0):

While this may not exactly answer your question it's worth mentioning about queues. For circular operations [`Queue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx)s could be a better data structure choice. To shift places it could be as simple as:

```
public static void Rotate<T>(this Queue<T> items, int places)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < places; i++)
        items.Enqueue(items.Dequeue());
}
```

E.g.

```
var q = new Queue<int>(new[] { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 });
q.Rotate(3);
```

Queues are also a lot more efficient than `List<T>`s for dequeuing operation since it doesnt have to remove from top and push entire block of array one up (read about it here: [Queue<T> vs List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380692/queuet-vs-listt)) or arrays which involves copying of the entire array.

Comment: Isn't this shifting to the left ? Try `q.Shift(2);`

Comment: @user3185569 I get `40,50,60,70,20,30`. Isn't that what's expected?

Comment: shouldn't that be `60,70,20,30,40,50` ? Shifting each element 2 places **To the Right** ? Or am I missing something here ?

Comment: @user3185569 Ah who knows. In that case it's a matter of adjusting the for loop.