# Is there a way to remove an item from a queue?

Tags: vb.net

I am using the [Queue(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) class

I know, first in, first out.

Say while doing that I sometimes want to take out some T item randomly that's not necessarily in first.

How would I do so?

Comment: Would this maybe be the answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531191/c-sharp-adding-a-removeint-index-method-to-the-net-queue-class

Comment: There is no easy way it seems.

Comment: I dont think it was designed to work that way, only workaround hacks.

Answer (score 1):

No straight forward way to do this, I'm afraid.
You can use a workaround like this, but it will hurt performance and I'm not sure it will keep the order correct:

```
Dim myQueue = New Queue(Of MyType)()
' Populate queue here...
Dim muList = myQueue.ToList()
muList.RemoveAt(1)
myQueue.Clear()
muList.ForEach(Function(item) myQueue.Enqueue(item))
```

Comment: For my purpose I use hashset and queue. Ha  ha ha

Comment: Same difference :-)